# How do I install Windows 3.11 on Virtual PC 2007?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-3.1

Just for fun....

I downloaded windows 3.11 and virtual pc 2007 from my MSDN subscription.  I've never actually installed this before.

A few ideas come to mind

1. Create an iso with the win3.11 files on it.  However, when I capture the iso from vpc it doesn't do anything.
2. Create a floppy disk image with the files on it.  The total size of win 3.11 is greater than 5MB so I need to split up the file onto multiple disks.  Not sure what disks the files should go on.

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - I have done it, and it is great fun!

Remember that you also need to download MS-Dos as Windows was not a stand alone operating system back then.

I installed it along the following:

The MS-Dos 6.2 disks come as .img files which can be mounted straight in to Virtual PC. Mount the first disk, and follow the on screen instructions.

Once dos is installed, mount the virtual hard drive to a physical drive on your host, and create a folder called "Winstall" (or whatever you want), then copy all the Windows setup files to this folder (if I remember correctly, they come as one large zip / compressed file).

unmount and launch the virtual machine, then type (assuming an untouched MS Dos installation):

```
cd winstall
setup
```

Then follow instructions and Windows should be installed in about 2-3 minutes from start to finish!

If you need any other help, please say!

Comment: Thanks for your response!  It might be a few days before I can try this out, things got busy at work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 3.11 requires there to be a base DOS installation before you install it.  You will need to first install DOS.  DOS typically can be installed using a bootable floppy.  Once DOS is installed, you would be able to run the Windows installer from the command prompt.

If you don't already have a copy of DOS you can head on over to the guys at [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) and get a free [compatible version](http://www.freedos.org/freedos/news/technote/200.html).